# Calculate mean value of column if multiple occurrences in another column

Tags: perl, unix

This is part of a tab separated file that I generated:

```
Sample      Gene    RPKM
MK_001_27   HPSE2   17.3767266340978
MK_003_11   HPSE2   51.1152373602497
MK_002_5    HPSE2   16.5372913024845
MK_001_23   HPSE2   25.8985857481585
MK_001_23   HPSE2   21.6045197173757
MK_001_27   HPSE2   139.450963428357
MK_001_23   HPSE2   36.7603351866179
MK_003_9    HPSE2   25.2860867858956
MK_001_22   HPSE2   100.915250867745
MK_003_9    HPSE2   35.078964327254
MK_003_12   HPSE2   34.078813048573
MK_003_9    HPSE2   13.5865540939141
```

Any gene is present in at least one sample. It may be present multiple times in the same sample.

I want to generate the mean of the *Reads Per Kilobase per Million* (RPKM) value and use it to replace multiple value for any given gene from the same sample

For example

```
MK_003_9    HPSE2   35.078964327254
MK_003_9    HPSE2   13.5865540939141
MK_003_9    HPSE2   25.2860867858956
```

becomes

```
MK_003_9    HPSE2   24.650535069
```

s there a way that you know of that could resolve this in Unix or in Perl?

Pseudocode

```
-For each line, combine column 0 (sample) and column 1 (gene) to create a "key" 
 though not always unique
-Run through the file to see if this "key" is present somewhere else
-Count the number of times this "key" is present
-If present > 1 time, calculate the mean of the RPKM values by sum()/count
-Create occurrence with this "key" and the new RPKM value
-Delete(?) the other corresponding "keys"
```

Comment: Yes. This is very easy in `perl`. However - Stack Overflow isn't a place to get people to do your work for you - it's about helping programmers solve programming problems. To this end - showing an attempt at solving your problem yourself elicits better responses.

Comment: I'm sorry, this wasn't my intention at all. I just wanted some leads because I honestly am a little bit lost. I know how to do it in pseudo code but the loops are hard for me. Sorry.

Comment: This is also very easy with `awk` -- associative arrays indexed on sample name to accumulate sum and count. Give it a shot.

Comment: @JeffY What do you think about that: I combine $1 and $2 and see if this combination is present somewhere else in the file. If yes, I somehow do the mean of the count of all these occurrences.

Comment: @user2697374 Yes combining $1 and $2 into a key/index is also an awk idiom: `++count[$1"."$2]` e.g.

Comment: pseudocoding your algorithm would be a good step in showing willing to solve it yourself. Specifically - given that input, what is the algorithm you'd use, and what is the desired output?

Comment: May your file contain data for multiple genes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite straightforward if you accumulate the contents of your data file into a Perl hash. You don't make it clear whether there may be multiple genes in a single file, so I've coded this for multiple samples and multiple genes

The program expects the input file as a parameter on the command line, and prints its output to STDOUT which may be redirected as normal

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::Util 'sum';

print scalar <>;  # Copy the header line

my %mean_rpkm;

while ( <> ) {
    my ($sample, $gene, $rpkm) = split;
    push @{ $mean_rpkm{$gene}{$sample} }, $rpkm;
}

for my $gene ( sort keys %mean_rpkm ) {

    for my $sample ( sort keys %{ $mean_rpkm{$gene} } ) {
        my $rpkm = $mean_rpkm{$gene}{$sample};
        my $mean = sum(@$rpkm) / @$rpkm;
        printf "%s\t%s\t%.3f\n", $sample, $gene, $mean;
    }
}
```

#### output

```
Sample      Gene    RPKM
MK_001_22   HPSE2   100.915
MK_001_23   HPSE2   28.088
MK_001_27   HPSE2   78.414
MK_002_5    HPSE2   16.537
MK_003_11   HPSE2   51.115
MK_003_12   HPSE2   34.079
MK_003_9    HPSE2   24.651
```

---

#### Update

The output from my solution is essentially unordered. I have sorted the genes and samples lexically, but you may want them in the same order as they appear in the input file. If so then you should say so

A useful intermediate solution is to install [`Sort::Naturally`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Naturally) (it's not a core module) and add

```
use Sort::Naturally 'nsort';
```

to the top of the above program. If you then replace both occurrences of `sort` with `nsort` then you will get this output. It may not be idea, but it's an improvement because it sorts `MK_003_9` *before* `MK_003_11` which a simple lexical sort doesn't do

```
Sample      Gene    RPKM
MK_001_22   HPSE2   100.915
MK_001_23   HPSE2   28.088
MK_001_27   HPSE2   78.414
MK_002_5    HPSE2   16.537
MK_003_9    HPSE2   24.651
MK_003_11   HPSE2   51.115
MK_003_12   HPSE2   34.079
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Borodin! I learned a lot and it works perfectly. I adapted it a little to my files.
Again, thank you!

Comment: Just to be sure..  push @{ $mean_rpkm{$gene}{$sample} }, $rpkm; says that the key is gene&sample and the value is rpkm right?

Answer (score 1):

Use [List::Util](http://p3rl.org/List::Util) to get the `sum` function. Store the RPKMs in a hash of arrays, the key being the sample. At the end, sum the arrays and divide by numbers of their elements:

```
perl -MList::Util=sum -lane '
    next if 1 == $.;
    push @{ $h{ $F[0] } }, $F[2];
    }{
    print $_, "\t", sum(@{ $h{$_} }) / @{ $h{$_} }
        for sort keys %h;
' < input-file > output-file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line.
- `-a` splits each line on whitespace into the @F array.
- `-l` adds newlines to prints.
- `$.` is the line number, it equals 1 for the header line.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

The core problem here is - if you have a condition like 'if there's multiple, delete the repeats' - you don't know if that condition applies until you've parsed the whole file.

You can read it all in, do some calculations (that are idempotent) and then dump some output.  A bit like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %stuff;

#iterate line by line of the special 'DATA' filehandle. 
#(You probably want <> instead)
while (<DATA>) {
   #split on any whitespace. 
   my ( $sample, $gene, $RPKM ) = split;
   #stuff the values into a list. 
   push( @{ $stuff{$sample}{$gene} }, $RPKM );
}

#iterate processed results and print them
foreach my $sample ( sort keys %stuff ) {
   foreach my $gene ( sort keys %{ $stuff{$sample} } ) {
      #sum and divide for average. 
      my $sum = 0;
      $sum += $_ for @{ $stuff{$sample}{$gene} };
      print join "\t", $sample, $gene, $sum / @{ $stuff{$sample}{$gene} },
        "\n";
   }
}

__DATA__
MK_001_27   HPSE2   17.3767266340978
MK_003_11   HPSE2   51.1152373602497
MK_002_5    HPSE2   16.5372913024845
MK_001_23   HPSE2   25.8985857481585
MK_001_23   HPSE2   21.6045197173757
MK_001_27   HPSE2   139.450963428357
MK_001_23   HPSE2   36.7603351866179
MK_003_9    HPSE2   25.2860867858956
MK_001_22   HPSE2   100.915250867745
MK_003_9    HPSE2   35.078964327254
MK_003_12   HPSE2   34.078813048573
MK_003_9    HPSE2   13.5865540939141
```

This gives:

```
MK_001_22   HPSE2   100.915250867745    
MK_001_23   HPSE2   28.0878135507174    
MK_001_27   HPSE2   78.4138450312274    
MK_002_5    HPSE2   16.5372913024845    
MK_003_11   HPSE2   51.1152373602497    
MK_003_12   HPSE2   34.078813048573 
MK_003_9    HPSE2   24.6505350690212
```

Note - it's sorted alphanumerically, because hashes are intrinsically unordered. IF you need to maintain ordering, it's a bit more complicated, but not impossible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, and for the comments. I learned a lot, thank you